# Accessibility: coders that stand up while coding

Tags: accessibility

I have a rare condition where often I cannot stand to sit and must stand up and walk around a little bit. I was wondering if anyone has a desk that allows them to code while standing up, and if these are available on the market to coders? I ask because most offices seem to set up with coders at low chairs where they would have to sit low at a regular low desk.

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: There are desks which can be changed in height, so people can stand or sit with the desk as high as they want. I'll go look what the desk brand is...

Comment: Thanks. Please let me know.